# Python posxifile.lock() IOError on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, locking

Implementing simple file locking fails on Mac OS X:

```
import posixfile

f = posixfile.open('a', 'w')
f.lock('w')
```

When run this causes the following exception:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Am I doing it wrong, or does OS X really not support this? If it's actually unsupported, what is it about OS X that prevents it from working?

I know I can use `fcntl` instead, but the syntax for `posixfile` looks so much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the big pink box near the very top of [the module's docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/posixfile.html):

> Deprecated since version 1.5: The locking operation that this module provides is done better and more portably by the fcntl.lockf() call.

That means it was deprecated in 1997. Mac OS X didn't even exist as an idea at that point, and the first version was released in 2001.

So, it's not surprising that nobody ever wrote an OS X-specific implementation of this module. What's surprising is that it wasn't removed entirely until 3.0.

---

If you want to know exactly why it doesn't work, look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/posixfile.py#l153). Without looking too far into the details, you can immediately see that there's code for *BSD, AIX, and something else unspecified (AT&T SysV and 100%-compatibles?). Notice that "darwin" isn't in the list of *BSD platforms, so it's going to fall through to the "something else". If you look at the OS X manpage for [`fcntl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man2/fcntl.2.html), its `struct flock` is clearly the BSD layout, as you'd expect, not the "something else" layout.

So, you're passing a struct of type(h)-whence(h)-start(l)-len(l)-sysid(h)-pid(h) to an API that expects start(q)-len(q)-pid(l)-type(h)-whence(h). You're lucky you get an I/O error instead of a segfault.

In fact, even if you added "darwin" to the list of BSD names, that code still wouldn't be right, because it throws away the top 32 bits of start and len and replaces them with pad zeros. (Which is probably wrong on modern FreeBSD and other *BSD platforms as well.)

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks. I hadn't read the web page, I found an example on some other site then used `pydoc` which doesn't mention deprecation. I'll switch to using `fcntl`.

Comment: @bahamat: If you like the interface of posixfile, I'll bet you could build an equivalent class yourself with a file plus fcntl. Someone might even have already done so on PyPI or ActiveState.